# Nodejs wait for a for loop to finish with mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a sql query which I execute in nodejs with the node-mysql library.

I want to run a for loop on the result of the query, like this:

```
sql.query(query, function(err, rows, field){
if (err) throw err;
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    do_something_complicated();
}
}
```

I tried using the async library and put the sql.query() in the first function and the rest of my code in the second function but it waits for the query to finish but not for the for loop.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the async library and their [`each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function.

```
sql.query(query, function(err, rows, field) {
    if (err) throw err;
    async.each(rows, function(row, callback) {
        do_something_complicated();
        // once finished call the callback
        // no arguments or null if successful, else with the error
        callback();
    }, function(err) {
        // handle errors and do something after each row has been iterated
    }
}
```

If you need the key/index use [`forEachOf`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachofobj-iteratee-callback) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code looks fine, everything directly after the for-loop should be executed after both, the query and the loop is done. Everything after your complete statement is executed immediately, since the sql.query function is asynchronous. Give the following implementation with async a try, it should work just fine:

```
async.waterfall([
    async.apply(sql.query, query),
    function(rows, field, callback){
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            do_something_complicated();
        }

        callback(null); // This is important, call callback after you are done with everything and pass null for the error parameter
    }
],
function(err){
    if(err) throw err;

    // Everything is executed by now
}
```